# how to typecast the objects created by newInstance() method of reflection API in java dynamically

Tags: java, reflection

How can i create a and clone and typecast the object?

```
Public int createObjec(Object object, String className) {    
//object may be User, Role or UserRole
// className is The Name of The Class

sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(dynamicObject); //dynamicObject may be User, Role or UserRole


}
```

Comment: Why don't you use generics instead.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution is to have a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) for handling object creation. 
So depending on the classname, create the correct type in the factory.